# How to properly prevent 504 Gateway Time-out?

Tags: nginx, php

I've an script that can run for about 10 min as it is a large data migration tool.

I have the problem that if i set `fastcgi_read_timeout 9900;` it never times out or if i set it to less then it times out before my script finished running.

I have taken away the `fastcgi_read_timeout 9900;` from `nginx.conf` and set  `max_execution_time = 1300;` in php.ini and I get a 504 Gateway Time-out now instead of looping until its done.

How can I properly set that the page should be live until the script finishes executing?

Answer (score 1):

open nginx.conf then after `http {` change this values as below

```
client_header_timeout 9999;
client_body_timeout 9999;
fastcgi_read_timeout 9999;
client_max_body_size 32m;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
```

if you have still the problem you can increase the values since it will be sloved